# Honda Accord incompatible brake caliper & bolt

Tags: honda, brake-calipers, bolts

I have a Honda Accord 2004 (https://honda-europe.epc-data.com/accord/2004_6mt/2895/).

I bought new front brake calipers for it with brake fluid bolt.

Somehow the bolt doesn't fit into the caliper though. I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong.

Brake Caliper: 45001-SEA-E01 (front left) - TRW (https://www.trwaftermarket.com/de/catalogue/product/BHX523E/)

Bolt: 46462-SE0-000 (https://www.akr-performance.de/p/honda-bremsschlauch-bolz-46462-SE0-000)

As far as I can tell, these numbers are correct.

I had a similar problem with rear calipers - also TRW brand, where the old bolt on the car did not fit into the new caliper.

What could be the problem? Should I try to buy a different brand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I replaced the front calipers on my 2011 Honda Accord I found that all of the calipers readily available at local auto stores were refurbs and the hole which accepts the banjo bolt was threaded differently compared to my original bolt.

[image]

Replacement bolts which would work in the hole were also of different shaft diameter so I had concern that this would cause restrictions in the brake fluid and ultimately cause some sort of failure or performance loss.

[image]

You need to get a true OEM caliper from an authorized dealer.

Since it was a weekend, the dealerships were closed but I ended up finding a knowledgeable person at Napa Auto Parts that was able to special order a non-refurbished caliper; this costed 3x the normal price of a refurb.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't understand why would manufacturers do this? Why have a different diameter for the bolt? It doesn't make any sense...???

Comment: @DávidMolnár See my update with pictures.

Comment: @DávidMolnár If my answer helped you then please consider marking it as "accepted" :-)

Comment: I'm not really sure where you've gotten the idea that a "refurb" in general won't do the job. Remember, a refurbished part (like a caliper) starts off as an OEM part, which is then refit with parts to make it good as new. I'm not saying your part didn't fit right or that the bolt didn't work, I'm saying a refurbished caliper starts out as a worn out OEM part. It's not like they intentionally went in and recut the threads to make them not fit your bolt. More than likely, the OEM changed the banjo bolt dimensions between years but didn't change the exterior dimensions of the caliper itself.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Sorry to have pigeon-holed the situation but that was a rough weekend in my books especially since I couldn't miss work on Monday. If my expectation of OEM to be plug-n-play in my Honda's OE components is misguided then please let me know. This issue has clearly affected someone else. If I recall correctly then it was visible on the refurbed caliper that it was in fact re-threaded; all of them, regardless of AutoZone, Advance Auto, or Napa.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - No,OEM should be plug-n-plan, no doubt ... I'm saying that the refurb parts should match up. If it doesn't, then take it back and get what does. I realize it doesn't always work because of the stupidness of OEM and how they change things seemingly ever year for little things like a banjo bolt. Two years might look the same, but have subtle differences like the banjo, so a refurb outfit might not notice it. It DOES happen. I'm suggesting it's not as often as you are suggesting ... in fact my experience with refurb is actually quite good. Why spend more when you don't have to.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 That weekend alone I bought and returned calipers 2 times before it dawned on me to just bring the banjo bolt with me. All of the off-the-shelf calipers had the same exact issue at all 3 chains. Like my post said, I was lucky enough to find a knowledgeable person at NAPA that was able to order something for 3x the refurb price. I'll remove my rant about OEM but a few years prior to that situation I was doing my exhaust and the pipe bends were off ever so slightly that it fit extra snug against the bottom of my car.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - Don't confuse "aftermarket" with "refurbished" ... Big difference. Also, I'm not trying to say you're lying or your situation was something different then you stated. I'm sure it was sucky. I'm just trying to say, I believe your experience is in the minority. I've very rarely ran into issues with refurbed parts fitting. My main point is, our experiences differ, therefore it is a more subjective topic than objective, meaning there's a lot of opinion thrown in on either position. IOW: MIleage may differ :o)

Comment: I don't get your argument about money - how does it make them more money to use a different pitch in the thread? Is it about buying the bolt from them - isn't it a very inexpensive item?

Comment: @DávidMolnár Sorry, that was a rant. See Paulster's comments about OEM and refurbs.

Comment: I ordered a new part, different brand (Brembo), not OEM, but it works perfectly well.